# Finding the smallest possible value of $n$ for $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been given the arguments and modulus of **some** values of $x^{1/n}$, where $x$ is a complex number and $n$ is a positive integer. These values are called $x_1$ and $x_2$.

$arg(x_1) = \frac{7\pi}{18}$ and $arg(x_2) = \frac{5\pi}{9}$.
The modulus of all these values is 2. So $|x_1| = |x_2| = 2$

I want to find the smallest possible value of $n$, but I am not sure how to approach this. So far, I have tried converting the values into their polar forms and setting the imaginary component to $0$ or the real component to $0$ and solving accordingly.

But I'm not sure how to approach the question as:

1. $z$ is a complex number instead of just real or imaginary, and
2. I only have some of the values of $x^{1/n}$ and I am not sure how to proceed with this information.

(Edited for clarity and formatting)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: The difference of arguments is $\frac{2\pi}n\Rightarrow n_{\text{min}}=12$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why we use the difference of arguments here, and how it becomes $\frac{2\pi}{n} = 12$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n$ $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ roots of a complex number have arguments spaced by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ (they form the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in the Argand diagram), so any two such roots have arguments differing by an integer multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Here the difference is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, so $n$ must be $12$ (or a multiple thereof).